# I deleted "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" library - I think I lost everything

Tags: command-line, python, data-recovery, libraries, recovery-mode

### **Context**

I am a novice with Ubuntu. I have been using the 16.04 LTS version for a while now, and I am just starting to understand some basic concepts. Sadly, I think that today I went a bit too far out of my comfort zone and potentially deleted part of my last year work forever. I seriously would appreciate any help.

It all started today, after running a

```
conda update -all
```

instead of my usual

```
conda update conda
```

just because I wanted to be sure that my [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) would update completely on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The update itself seemed to work fine, but then when I wanted to run a python script in my base environment (the only one I have/had), I got an error that I had never seen before. As I cannot access my Ubuntu anymore, I am forced to describe part of these things by heart, so forgive me if I lack in precison of terms. So the problem was related to my `libstdc++.so.6` file, which was missing `CXXABI_1.3.11` (by the way, I am 100% sure that these 2 last names are correct).

### **Breaking Ubuntu**

I started browsing StackOverflow and other websites looking for an answer, and many of them presented solutions similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found), but they did not work for me, assuming I was applying them right. Basically I was trying to add some lines in my `~/.bashrc` hoping that something would have worked. I know this is not a great practice, but I was just trying to solve what I thought was a minor annoyance, in order to be able to start my actual work, which was already a lot by itself. Anyway, I then found [this solution](https://www.programmersought.com/article/41851413652/), and applied it step by step. I almost copy-pasted all the commands with little care, just changing my personal folder name where necessary. After the last step, i.e.

```
sudo strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep 'CXXABI'
```

my output was "file not found". I then traced back all the steps and discovered that in the 4th step I was actually supposed to remove that `libstdc++.so.6` library, so that is the command that created my problem. In fact, after trying those 6 steps, everything stopped working: Firefox, VS Code, etc. I decided to reboot the OS, and I discovered that I now cannot even access it anymore.

### **What I want**

If there is even a small chance I can at least recover my files (or better my entire OS), I do not want to miss it. So, as I see that I can still access recovery mode and the other alternative options in the recovery menu, like "dpkg - repair broken packages", I do not want to experiment alone anymore. I am currently using this PC with dual boot option, if this matters.

### **Log of shell commands**

Here is the list of all the commands involved, i.e. the "conda update" attempt plus the ones reported in the tutorial:

```
conda update -all
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
sudo find / -name "libstdc++.so.6*"
cp /home/MYUSERNAMEHERE/anaconda2/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo rm -rf libstdc++.so.6
sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.25 libstdc++.so.6
sudo strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep 'CXXABI'
```

All the commands after the first one are coming from the tutorial; I just adapted a single folder name, the one labelled above as "MYUSERNAMEHERE".

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` should be a symbolic link to an actual file like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.n.m` so if you can get access to any kind of shell (or even `busybox ln`) you should be able to repair it

Comment: This might not be easily repaired.  I suggest that you use installation media to boot into a live session. You can mount your hard drive and transfer files somewhere else.  Since 16.04 reaches end of life this month, it's a good time to install a newer version of Ubuntu.  Use this experience to start keeping backups of files you can't stand to lose.

Comment: There are free and pay recovery programs for Linux.  Problem is they are not plug and play, you need to do research to use them well.  Professional recovery people be your best bet if it needs to be done fast.  Do not use partition and/or drive, unless to copy it to another drive.

Comment: From a root shell in recovery mode, please run `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so*` and tell us what you see. If plain `ls` doesn't work try `busybox ls`

Comment: Thank you @Nmath. Then, using a live session, I can thus view all my files on that Ubuntu partition, or am I misunderstanding it? In either case, this is a viable solution, and I will go for this if I cannot avoid re-installing Ubuntu. As a side note, as of now I would still need to keep the 16.04 version due to compatibility constraints imposed by some software I use (kinetic ROS, for example). Also, from now on I will surely store all my essential files in more than one location or backup them, that's granted.

Comment: Thanks @crip659. I am considering both options you suggested. Anyway, as of now I might want to first try the quicker routes suggested by the other two guys. Even if I imagine that every time I use the partition I may risk to delete something that would have been otherwise recoverable, I think that a minor number of reboots and shell commands can be worth trying.

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. Your answer was the one that surely sparked the most hope in me. Even if it is clear that I am not confident with these kind of issues, I think that I have a grasp about the idea you are suggesting when you talk about fixing the symbolic linking. I collected the info you asked for, and I uploaded a screenshot [here] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sule53IoQYttPyaCiQ3_5Fov0rl_05Q4/view?usp=sharing). Sorry for the quality of the image, I could hardly do any better. I highlighted the two commands you suggested and reported both, as the outputs are not identical.

Comment: A live session is like a portable version of Ubuntu.  You can mount the hard drive where Ubuntu is installed.  Once mounted, the volume will be accessible from the file manager. You can mount another volume, like an external hard drive, and that will allow you to copy files